# Non-Noetherian ring with a single prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> What are the most simple examples of a commutative ring $R$ satisfying both of the following two properties:
>   1. $R$ is not Noetherian.
>   2. $R$ has exactly one prime ideal.

Comment: Hint: you can get an example of this by finding a ring whose maximal ideal consists of nilpotent elements but is not nilpotent (e.g. a suitable quotient of $k[x_1, x_2, \dots]$).

Comment: @Akhil: I was trying to look at a quotient of the form k[x1,...]/(x1, x2^2,...xn^n,...), but it doesn't seem to work. An additional hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @spec: Dear Spec, Actually, what you just described is precisely the example I had in mind; that ring has one prime ideal (namely, that generated by all the $x_i$), which is not nilpotent.

Answer (score 11):

Try $k[x_1, x_2, ...]/(x_i x_j)$ for all $i, j$.

Comment: Sadly, no. The ideal `$\langle x_j \langle_{j > 1}$` is prime, since the quotient is $k[x_1]$.

Comment: @David: I deliberately did not exclude the case $i = j$. I'm pretty sure this works. The quotient by the ideal you describe is $k[x_1]/(x_1^2)$.

Comment: In other words, if $I = (x_1,\ldots,x_n,\ldots)$, then this is $k[x_1,x_2,\ldots]/I^2$.

Comment: Oh, I misread you. You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 6):

$$R:= k[x_1, x_2, x_3, \cdots ]/\langle x_1^2,\ x_2^2=x_1,\ x_3^2=x_2,\ x_4^2=x_3,\ \cdots \rangle$$

Remember that prime ideals are precisely the kernels of maps to fields. If $K$ is any field, and we have a map $\phi: R \to K$, then $\phi(x_1)=0$ and hence $\phi(x_2) =0$ and hence $\phi(x_3)=0$ and so forth, so the only prime ideal is $\langle x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots \rangle$.

To see that this is not noetherian, note that $(0) \subsetneq (x_1) \subsetneq (x_2) \subsetneq (x_3) \subsetneq \cdots$ is an ascending chain of ideals that doesn't terminate.

Of course, the specific exponent $2$ isn't important. The key is to make a sequence of variables $x_1$, $x_2$, ..., all of which are nilpotent, but so that you can kill $x_1$, $x_2$, ..., $x_k$ while not killing the later $x$'s.

Comment: Sorry for reviving the post, but aren't prime ideals kernels of those which map to integral domain?

Comment: You can compose with the embedding of the integral domain into its field of fractions, and the kernel remains unchanged. There's no requirement that the map has to be surjective.

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to ask for one nonzero prime ideal, then for any prime $p$ the ring of integers of ${\mathbf C}_p$ (the $p$-adic complex numbers) is an example. The only nonzero prime ideal in that ring is its maximal ideal, which is not finitely generated.

Comment: And if you form $\mathcal O_{\mathbf C_p}/p,$ this will be non-Noetherian with just a single prime ideal.

Answer (score 4):

I thought this observation might be useful to future viewers other than the OP. If a mod thinks this is old enough for a new topic, please do.

Since the nilradical is  in every prime, the condition of having only one prime ideal (which will also be maximal) is equivalent to the condition that the nilradical is a maximal ideal.

Thus one immediately obtains a large class of examples as mentioned by the posters above as non noetherian rings of the form $k[N]$ where  $k$ is a field and $N$ is a set of nilpotent elements. So in fact, in Qiaochu's example it is enough to take the simpler quotient $k[x_1,x_2,...]/(x_1^2,x_2^2,...)$.

Also note as in the examples of the form $k[N]$ given above, in any example the maximal ideal will need to be be infinitely generated since a ring is noetherian iff every prime is finitely generated.

I do wonder if there are examples not of the form $k[N]$.

Comment: I have no idea what this answers brings new to the question. Moreover, there are some answers involving rings of algebraic integers which seem to answer your last question.

Comment: Thank you, it was not immediately obvious to me why the quotient of the localization of the ring of algebraic integers is not isomorphic to $k[N]$.

Answer (score 2):

Take a localization $O:=R_M$ of the ring $R$ of all algebraic integers at a maximal ideal $M$. Then $O/xO$ has exactly one prime for every non-zero $x\in MO$.