# When does a ring have a flat noetherian extension?

Tags: commutative-algebra

The title says it all:

Let $A$ be a commutative ring.

Are there any interesting known conditions on $A$ (other then being noetherian of course...) to ensure existence of a (non-zero) commutative noetherian ring $B$, and a flat ring map $A\to B$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is integral, you can take $B$ to be the fraction field $K(A)$ of $A$. The morphism $A\to K(A)$ is flat. In general, you  (edit: **can't**) probably take $B$ to be the total field of fractions.

Comment: Are you claiming that the generalized fraction field will always be noetherian?

Comment: Actually, let me take that back. That can't be correct. What about taking $B$ to be the localization of $A$ at some minimal prime ideal? In this case $B$ is a local zero-dimensional ring. Aren't these always noetherian?

Comment: I proved a theorem which is correct for any ring $A$ which satisfies the condition of the above question. I know that my theorem is not true for any ring, so assuming my proof is correct, the answer to the above question cannot be - for any ring.

Comment: Dear @Harry: Dimension zero local rings do not have to be Noetherian. See the link in the comments to the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by Harry's observation in the discussion, here is another way to get examples of what you seek. If you take any ring $A$ having a minimal prime ideal $p$ that is finitely generated (but $A$ is not necessarily Noetherian), then $A_p$ is a Noetherian ring (this follows from the result that if all the prime ideals of a ring are finitely generated, then the ring is Noetherian). You will then get a flat ring map $A \rightarrow A_p$, but $A$ is not Noetherian.

Comment: Thanks, so am I correct that not all rings have minimal primes which are finitely generated?

Comment: Yes you are. See the discussion here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39458/non-noetherian-ring-with-a-single-prime-ideal

Comment: Thanks for both of you. That's funny, because now I actually proved that there is a ring which does not satisfy the above question. Any flat extension of it is not noetherian :)

Comment: well, any domain will do the case...

Comment: You are correct. I will edit my answer.

Comment: For an example of a non-Noetherian ring of dim $\geq 1$, I think you can take the ring $k[x_1, x_2, \dots]/(x^2_1)$, and the minimal prime ideal $(x_1)$.

Comment: Also, I am not sure why you say dimension $0$ rings have only one prime ideal.

Comment: @anonymous: so what is the example of a ring without flat noetherian extension ?

Comment: There was an unfortunate mistake in my proof, so I don't know it anymore :(